# Remove widgets from other themes in Sublime Text 4

Tags: user-interface, themes, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I installed the Guna theme which brings a nice color scheme that I would like to keep; however, the **theme** comes with a clock and weather widget that I can't remove even if I set the theme back to default.

[image: Clock widget from the Guna theme, still showing in the Default theme.]

I have tried setting the layer where the clock texture is contained, to have zero opacity, but then the most I got it to do was showing the clock in a different color.

The following lines are in the Guna theme's default settings, starting at line 166:

```
{
    "class": "sidebar_container",
    "layer0.texture": "Guna/assets/simple/sidebar/sidebar-bg-clock-nb.png",
    "layer0.inner_margin": [15, 55, 15, 0],
    //"layer0.inner_margin": [15, 70, 15, 0],
    //"layer0.inner_margin": [15, 92, 15, 0],
    "layer0.tint": "color(var(--background))",
    "layer0.opacity": 1,
    "content_margin": [0, 45, 0, 0],
    //"content_margin": [0, 60, 0, 0],
    //"content_margin": [0, 82, 0, 0],
},
{
    "class": "sidebar_container",
    "settings": ["gnwidgx"],
    "layer0.texture": "Guna/assets/simple/sidebar/sidebar-bg-nb.png",
    "layer0.inner_margin": [15, 55, 15, 0],
    "layer0.tint": "color(var(--background))",
    "layer0.opacity": 1,
    "content_margin": [0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

I tried setting the content margin to [0,0] for the clock widget (like I've seen it's possible to do to hide file icons), like so:

```
{
    "variables": {

    },
    "rules":
    [
        {
            "class": "sidebar_container",
            "content_margin": [0,0],
            "layer0.opacity": 0
        },
        {
            "class": "sidebar_container",
            "content_margin": [0,0],
            "layer1.opacity": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

And the result is this: every sidebar element, including the files and folders, bugs out and leaves a trail as if I were shift+dragging everything in mspaint.

[image: Result of my custom theme settings]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The layer1.opacity line is there in my custom settings because in the theme's original settings (I left it out because it was too long) there's a "layer1" of which texture is also related to the clock:

(starting at line 188 in the original file:)
```{ "class": "sidebar_container", "layer1.inner_margin": [120, 40, 0, 0], "settings" : ["gnc_h00",   "gnwidg1"], "layer1.texture": "Guna/assets/simple/sidebar/clock/clock_h00.png", "layer1.opacity": 1 }```
And 23 other similar lines detailing more clock textures for layer1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Guna has a setting that adds the widgets (clock, weather, etc.) to all themes. Fortunately, it can be turned off. Select **`Preferences → Package Settings → Guna → Settings`** and add the following to the right pane:

```json
    "sidebar_widget_on_other_theme": false,
```

You can turn off the widgets in Guna itself with this setting:

```json
    "sidebar_widget": [],
```

Valid values for that array are empty (as above) or any combination of `"clock"`, `"weather"`, and `"date"`.

Save the right pane when you're done, and the settings *should* be applied immediately. If not, you might need to restart Sublime.

Comment: Amazing! It worked instantly. Thank you for illuminating me on using the **Preferences -> Package Settings** submenu, it went over my head.
Thanks and regards!